# Internet Explorer stops responding

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm running a small piece of javascript which is show/hiding approx 170 table  rows. In IE9, this is intermittently causing the browser to "stop responding" and to die. I get the dialog saying that "Internet Explorer has stopped working...".

In Chrome, its fine. The operation takes around 1 sec to complete (and when it works in IE it takes 1-2 seconds).

All I am doing is calling this line, in a recursive function, 170 times (id is a guid uniquely identifying each of the table tr rows):

```
$("#" + id).css("display", "block");
```

If I introduce a timeout in my code of 1 millisecond between showing rows, it works, everytime!

```
setTimeout(function () { $("#" + id).css("display", "block"); }, 1);
```

Have also tried jquery show method as well.

I also get an error in the event log as follows:

Faulting application name: IEXPLORE.EXE, version: 9.0.8112.16448, time stamp: 0x4fecf1b7
Faulting module name: MSHTML.dll, version: 9.0.8112.16448, time stamp: 0x4fecfb0e
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x002cd4e6
Faulting process id: 0x1764
Faulting application start time: 0x01cd9725ec072ed0
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\MSHTML.dll
Report Id: 721d0e53-03c5-11e2-98c9-005056c00008

Has anyone else experienced this kind of behaviour when performing a repetitive task?

Answer (score -1):

please don't go with recursive function
as it is Bad practice , there must be some memory leak in the code with 
setTimeout() , so it may be the reason WITH IE.

Comment: The recursive function is required as i have a table with a 1000+ rows which are laid out in a parent / child grouped format. There are 4 levels, so recursion is used to hide child rows before hiding me (if you know what i mean).

Its probably the use of a table thats primarily at fault, but this was inherited code that needs a quick fix.

Thanks for your response.